# SqlDataAdapter.Fill populate no rows in given DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, sqldataadapter

all.

Here is my code.

```
private void FillData(DataTable data, FilterModel filter){
  var cmdStr = MySqlCmdGenerator.Generate(filter);
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, connection_))
  using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)){
    da.Fill(data);
  }
}

public DataTable GetData(IEnumerable<FilterModel> filters){
  var data = new DataTable("mydata");
  foreach (var filter in filters){
    FillData(data);
  }
  return data;
}
```

It's a very simple code, which just use `SqlDataAdapter` to `Fill` datatable according to the `filters`.

The problem is that sometimes `GetData` method returns empty datatable.

First I execute the generated query on SQL Server Management Studio, and it returns correct result (it contains about 100,000 records). 
Then I have used Sql Server Profiler to profile what happened in server, and get some errors:

```
Sort Warnings  
RPC:Completed (TextData: Query with a given filter)  
Hash Warning  
Sort Warnings  
RPC:Completed (TextData: Query with a given filter)  
User Error Message (TextData: The statement has been terminated.)
Attention  
Audit Logout  
RPC:Completed (TextData: sp_reset_connection)
```

(occurs in this order)

After google the error but I could not figure out what is exactly happen in server and application.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Differences between results from a .NET application and those from SQL Server Management Studio are often due to different configuration of ANSI settings for the SQL Server connection.

This assumes you've eliminated the obvious error causes, e.g. you're inadvertently connection to different databases from the two environments.

You can see the settings used by SQL Server Management Studio in Tools / Options / Query Execution / SQL Server / ANSI.  On my installation they default to:

```
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

I suggest you try switching these OFF one by one in Management Studio to attempt to reproduce the configuration used by .NET.  Once you understand what's happening, you can do one of:

- Add SET statements to your .NET query
- Modify your query so it isn't dependent on these settings (may need to add ISNULL or explicit tests for NULL).